# UML inheritance - why is the direction of arrow from the subclass to the parent-class?

Tags: oop, object, inheritance, uml, diagram

[image: Image: Class B extends class A. Then Why is the arrow from B to A?]

In the image above class B inherits class A. If B inherits all A's methods, shouldn't the arrow be from A to B? In my opinion it would make more sense if the arrow was from A to B.

Is there a reason that the direction of the arrow is this way and not the other way around? I would love to hear the explanation. 
Thank you.

EDIT: I know that this is the way that UML is designed, and that the diagram above is true according to the rules of UML, but my question is ***why*** UML made the arrow go this way .

Comment: I voted to leave open; this isn't a matter of opinion, it's a matter of history. It was a matter of opinion until the decision was made and the standard published, back in the dawn of time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason is that in your case `B` references (or as you will calls out to) `A`. There is no knowledge about `B` in `A`, so no arrow from A to B, but rather the other way around.

The UML entity diagram is not about who 'gets' what, but rather about who references/knows about who.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. When I think about it, if you implement it in Java you would write "`class B extends A`" and not the other way around. `A` wouldn't be affected - it wouldn't "know" about it.

Comment: very nice answer especially the part "There is no knowledge about `B` in `A`"

Comment: I think another way to look at this is using mathematical concept of *function* or *morphism*, or even generally speaking *mapping*. The relation of 1 to m, or 1 to 1 is necessary for the relation to be a *morphism*. In the type inheritance, there can be one or more than one sub-class for one super-class. So for the mapping to meet mathematical condition for a morphism, sub-classes must be the domain, where the mapping arrow starts―arrow tails are pointing. And the codomain(range) is super-classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the way UML had been designed. The arrow points to the general class. The special one inherits and adds/replaces functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But **why** are the arrows this way? What is the logic behind it? Is there a documentation about it or something I can read about? Thanks.

Comment: Sure: https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/ for the whole thing and https://www.uml-diagrams.org if you need some lighter digest.